# Upgrading to commerce-stripe v4.0.0

Tags: plugin-commerce-stripe

I am just upgrading my clients site and have upgraded all plugins including commerce-stripe up to v3.1.1. I want to upgrade to v4.0.0 for commerce-stripe but keep getting the following message - does anyone know what i need to do?

```
~$ composer update
You made a reference to a non-existent script @pre-craft-update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires craftcms/commerce-stripe 4.0.0 -> satisfiable by craftcms/commerce-stripe[4.0.0].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: stripe/stripe-php[v7.0.0, ..., v7.128.0, v8.0.0, ..., v8.12.0, v9.0.0, ..., v9.9.0, v10.0.0, ..., v10.21.0].
    - enupal/stripe[5.1.1, ..., 5.3.1] require stripe/stripe-php ^7.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v7.0.0, ..., v7.128.0].
    - craftcms/commerce-stripe 4.0.0 requires stripe/stripe-php ^10.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v10.0.0, ..., v10.21.0].
    - Root composer.json requires enupal/stripe ^5.1.1 -> satisfiable by enupal/stripe[5.1.1, ..., 5.3.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error messages line by line, then it becomes clear what the problem is.

> - Root composer.json requires craftcms/commerce-stripe 4.0.0 -> satisfiable by craftcms/commerce-stripe[4.0.0].
> [...]
> - Root composer.json requires enupal/stripe ^5.1.1 -> satisfiable by enupal/stripe[5.1.1, ..., 5.3.1].

This tells you have both the `craftcms/commerce-stripe` and the `enupal/stripe` package as direct dependencies in your project, because you have both of those plugins installed.

> - enupal/stripe[5.1.1, ..., 5.3.1] require stripe/stripe-php ^7.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v7.0.0, ..., v7.128.0].

One of those plugins requires the package `stripe/stripe-php` in version 7.x …

> - craftcms/commerce-stripe 4.0.0 requires stripe/stripe-php ^10.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v10.0.0, ..., v10.21.0].

… but the other plugin requires the *same* package in version 10.x.

You can only have one version of a package installed at the same time. But both plugins require different versions of the `stripe/stripe-php` package, so it's impossible for Composer to select one version that fits both requirements.

Therefore you get this:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

To resolve this, you have some options:

- Ask the maintainer of the [`enupal/stripe`](https://github.com/enupal/stripe) plugin to update their plugin to support version 10.x of the package.
- Ask the maintainer of the [`craftcms/commerce-stripe` plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe) to support older versions of that package, including 7.x.
- Fork either plugin and update it yourself to support one of those versions.
- Uninstall one of the plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed answer - much appreciated